# UNO - No events bubbling to my native WASM control

Tags: uno-platform

I have created a blank UNO Solution and added this as my MainPage:

```
[HtmlElement("div")]
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.SetHtmlAttribute("id", "MyDiv");
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => //<- Wait until page is rendered
        {
            // add a simple button
            WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS("document.getElementById(\"MyDiv\").innerHTML = \"<button onclick=\\\"alert('clicked')\\\">test</button>\"");
        });

    }
}
```

After that I started the WASM project. As expected I see a website containg a button. Unfortunately the button seems to recieve no events at all, there is no hover effect and when I click the button nothing happens.

Is there a setting in UNO where I can force the events to bubble into my native control?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The trick was to wrap the code wihin an UIElement:

```
[HtmlElement("div")]
public sealed class CustomControl1 : UIElement
{
   public CustomControl1()
   {
            
       this.SetHtmlAttribute("id", "MyDiv");
       Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => //<- Wait until page is rendered
       {
           // add a simple button
            WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS("document.getElementById(\"MyDiv\").innerHTML = \"<button onclick=\\\"alert('clicked')\\\">test</button>\"");
       });
   }       
}
```

Now I can use this Control within my MainPage:

```
<Grid  Margin="20" >
   <CustomControl1></CustomControl1>
</Grid>
```

Mouse behavior is as expected again.